# How to set invocation count of a test method using TestNG listeners?

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, testng, listeners

I am trying to set the invocation count for a specific test case . The following  code is written for listener. The goal is to loop a specific test method for a given number of times. the listener is working fine but **setInvocationCount** is not working as expected.

Listener class :-

```
public class InvokedListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    String count = System.getProperty("count", "100");
    int counter = Integer.parseInt(count);
    int count1;

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

        System.out.println("before invocation of " + method.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
        String methodName = method.getTestMethod().getMethodName();

        if (methodName.contains("TC_02_InstructorCreatesCourse")) {
            System.out.println("The listener is activated for:-" + method.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
            method.getTestMethod().setInvocationCount(20);
            System.out.println("Invocation count is set to :-" + counter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        System.out.println("after invocation " + method.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
    }
```

testNG xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
        <listener class-name="InvokedLister" />

    </listeners>

<test name="CourseCreation"
    preserve-order="true"  enabled="true">
    <classes>
        <class
            name="TestCases" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

TEST CASES:-

```
@Test
public void TC_01_LoginToSSOApplicationViaInstructor() {     
    System.out.println("1");
}

@Test
public void TC_02_InstructorCreatesCourse() {     
    System.out.println("2");

}

@Test
public void TC_03_LoginToSSApplicationViaStudent() {
    System.out.println("3");
}

@Test
public void TC_04_EnrollStudentInCourse() {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IAnnotationTransformer` or `IAnnotationTransformer2`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) are a better listener choice for your purpose:

```
public class MyTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

  private final int counter;

  public MyTransformer() {
    String count = System.getProperty("count", "100");
    counter = Integer.parseInt(count);
  }

  public void transform(ITest annotation, Class<?> testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    if (testMethod.getName().contains("TC_02_InstructorCreatesCourse")) {
      System.out.println("The listener is activated for:-" + testMethod.getName());
      annotation.setInvocationCount(20);
      System.out.println("Invocation count is set to :-" + counter);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more insight why this is a better listener?

Comment: Because IAnnotationTransformer is used by TestNG before the run of tests (init phase) and IInvokedMethodListener is used during the run. Changing values during the run phase could or could not work.

Comment: Thank you , Julien Herr.